# car parking Dataset in US

Tags: data-request, usa, parking

I am looking for a dataset of car-parking in any city. I am doing a research about car-parking / traffic and their impact in the life of US cities.

Is there any public dataset that you recommend  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're not looking for real time data, you might want to search on the term 'parking study', which tends to look at the availability of parking in various areas.

I would assume that cities that have gone to dynamic pricing aka 'active parking management' would need to be collecting the data to set their pricing ... so [Seattle](http://www.seattle.gov/transportation/parking/reports.htm) and [San Francisco](http://sfpark.org/how-it-works/open-data-page/) would be prime candidates ... unless you're looking for more typical parking data.

Comment: i was going to say search seattle by transportation https://data.seattle.gov/browse?category=Transportation

Answer (score 5):

I've seen datasets on car parking locations in a number of city open data portals. I did a quick Google (city car parking dataset) to find a few to get you started:

http://data.sa.gov.au/dataset?tags=city+parking

*Displays the number of current car parking spaces available at each of the UPark car parks located in the city. Further information re UPark locations, operating hours, rates...*

http://www.opendatanottingham.org.uk/dataset.aspx?id=44

*The location of car parks. This dataset includes information about facilities available at each car park and information about fees, opening hours and contact details.*

https://data.cityofchicago.org/Transportation/CTA-Park-and-Ride-kml/2cys-9ux7

*CTA Park and Ride - Polygon data representing CTA park and ride locations. Details include number of spaces, cost, and rail station.*

http://www.carlisle.gov.uk/council-and-democracy/freedom-of-information/datasets/datasets-available-for-re-use.aspx

*Car park (pay and display) locations and spaces Finance/Car parking csv 
Car park (pay and display) charges Finance/Car parking csv*

http://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/088849ae28bf460982c7e6fd2bd660bd_0

*Car Parking - Galway City Data*

http://data.gov.au/dataset/parking-meter-areas-brisbane-city-council

*Datset includes: meter number, meter category, max stay (hours), operational day, operational time, restrictions, street, suburb, precinct, tariff ($/Hr), tariff maximum, latitude and longitude.*

Comment: You can find my list of US Cities with open data portals here. Just search each one (lol): http://www.opengeocode.org/opendata/

Comment: Most of the datasets you have listed are outside US.

Answer (score 1):

You could search for relevant datasets among the state and local datasets featured on Data.gov.
http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?groups=local#topic=local_navigation

You can also search the local datasets on data.gov specifically for the term parking:
http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=Parking&sort=none&groups=local&ext_location=&ext_bbox=&ext_prev_extent=-142.03125%2C8.754794702435605%2C-59.0625%2C61.77312286453148#topic=local_navigation